# Find the two most different means of a series

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a series of values, for each year from 1936 to 2015 one value. Now I am searching an elegant solution (in R) to identify two consecutive(!) periods (each with a minimum (or maximum) of n years, let's say 15 years) which have two means that are most different from each other. Thus, I am searching a specific year to divide the series into two groups.

Of course, I can handle this with a loop to compare each combination of groups against each other, but I wonder if there is a better way. Normally I am working with ggplot and dplyr systematics. So, any hint would be beneficial.

```
require(dplyr)

structure(list(year = c(1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 
1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 
1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 
1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 
1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), q = c(1.31495, 0.81315, 
0.60275, 0.9025, 1.11875, 1.1897, 0.82025, 0.5936, 0.90045, 1.37755, 
1.18465, 2.5685, 2.52925, 0.59695, 0.8666, 0.97685, 1.63635, 
1.30825, 1.4089, 1.99535, 1.4652, 0.7518, 1.2352, 1.5946, 1.19385, 
1.0436, 0.80355, 0.6153, 0.68, 1.7616, 2.76765, 2.37105, 1.4026, 
0.87665, 0.76225, 0.73925, 0.7226, 0.9125, 2.02875, 1.81795, 
0.69295, 1.33245, 1.7908, 2.01205, 1.365, 1.6906, 2.40445, 1.52365, 
1.0436, 1.00605, 1.63635, 1.9244, 1.3984, 1.27735, 1.52365, 2.01205, 
1.26065, 1.69895, 2.24585, 2.17905, 1.68225, 1.49445, 1.4151, 
2.1164, 1.88265, 1.75745, 2.7175, 1.7157, 0.94675, 0.87455, 0.70465, 
0.8624, 1.01855, 1.3984, 1.9912, 1.54455, 2.5297, 2.513, 1.43185, 
0.89415)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-80L), .Names = c("year", "q"))
```

Expected outcome would be something like:

```
   year       q class   mean
  <dbl>   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
1  1936 1.31495     1 1.2563
2  1937 0.81315     1 1.2563
3  1938 0.60275     1 1.2563
4  1939 0.90250     1 1.2563
5  1940 1.11875     1 1.2563
6  1941 1.18970     1 1.2563
...
1  2010 1.99120     2 1.5877
2  2011 1.54455     2 1.5877
3  2012 2.52970     2 1.5877
4  2013 2.51300     2 1.5877
5  2014 1.43185     2 1.5877
6  2015 0.89415     2 1.5877
```

Comment: Please add the expected output, at least for few rows.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. One possibility would be an additional column in the data_frame with group "A" and group "B".

Comment: @mod_che Show us a small data.frame with what that might look like with a dataset with 5 rows, for example.

Comment: With `sapply` it doesn't seem too hard to find which 2 15year periods are the most different, but because it means sliding across the 80 years available, I'm not sure you why you would present that in dataframe format.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't be two 15-years periods, but at least 15 years in one period (than the other is 65 years long), or 16/64 or 17/63 etc....

Comment: Then, if I understood correctly, that is, you want to cover all of the 80years with the 2 period. `sapply`seems to be a good way to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it this way:

`n <- 15` (as you suggested)

`meanInfEq` is the mean of `q` computed over all years that are inferior or equal to a specific year, while `meanSup` is computed over the remaining years. `diff` is the absolute value of the difference of these two means:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(meanInfEq = q %>% cummean, 
         meanSup = q %>% rev %>% cummean %>% rev %>% lead,
         diff = abs(meanInfEq - meanSup))
```

Note that `rev %>% cummean %>% rev` is just a trick to compute the cumulative mean starting from the bottom of the dataframe.

We restrain `df` to focus on the periods of length greater or equal to `n`:

```
df2 <- df %>% filter(year %in% (1936+n-1):(2015-n+1))
```

Now we can find `yearCut`, defined as the year (or more exactly, **a** year) maximizing the absolute difference:

```
k <- which.max(df2$diff)

yearCut <- df2$year[k]
mean1 <- df2$meanInfEq[k]
mean2 <- df2$meanSup[k]

output <- df %>%
  mutate(class = ifelse(year <= yearCut, 1, 2),
         mean = ifelse(year <= yearCut, mean1, mean2)) %>%
  select(year, q, class, mean)
```

When `n` equals 15, `yearCut` is **1964** and the output looks as follows:

```
  year       q class     mean
 <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
  1936 1.31495     1 1.175462
  1937 0.81315     1 1.175462
  1938 0.60275     1 1.175462
  1939 0.90250     1 1.175462
  1940 1.11875     1 1.175462
  1941 1.18970     1 1.175462
 ...
  2010 1.99120     2 1.562204
  2011 1.54455     2 1.562204
  2012 2.52970     2 1.562204
  2013 2.51300     2 1.562204
  2014 1.43185     2 1.562204
  2015 0.89415     2 1.562204
```